# Generic method: Contraint with Interface, how to access properties

Tags: c#, properties, interface, generic-method

I want to access a property of a new created object within a generic method, which is constraint by an Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Since the Compiler knows that "T" is of the Type MyInterface it should be possible to access the properties of that inteface:

```
public T doSomething<T>(String value) where T : MyInterface, new()
{
    T entity =  new T();
    entity.Name = value;    
    return entity;
}
```

But it sais: *T does not have a definition for 'Name'*

If I can use an interface as a constraint here: Why isn't it possible to access its properties?

Comment: Do you have a `MyInterface` in another namespace?  Have you done a clean and rebuild?

Comment: It works fine for me. I dont have any issue

Comment: Is this really your _actual_ code?

Comment: Yes it's another namespace but I integrated it by "using" statement.
And no, this is not my actual code it's simplified.

Comment: mostly looks like namespace problem to me.Create a simple class and then try to implement your `MyInterface` in it. The complier will throw error if it is a namespace problem,let us know the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is correct for itself. Maybe you have different versions of your interface (MyInterface in different namespaces)? Check the namespaces / fully qualified names of the interface types. Also the check the assembly versions, if declaring types in another assembly...

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class Foo2 : MyInterface
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

...

```
    var foo = doSomething<Foo2>("test");
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Name);
```

Seems to work as long as your code has the namespace of your interface and concrete class in a using clause. Also, as a matter of convention MyInterface should be IMyInterface.